# По умолчанию вывести значение

Tags: javascript, html

Есть селект, при выборе которого берется значение с value и вставляется в div. Вопрос, как сделать, чтоб по умолчанию уже было 1 значение, а если выбираешь другое, то ставилась фраза руб.

```js
(function() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.selected'), function(e) {
    e.addEventListener("change", n)
  })

  function n(e) {
    var s = e.target;
    var v = s.parentNode.querySelector('.value');

    !+s.value && (v.style.display = 'none') || (v.style.display = 'inline-block', v.innerText = s.value)
  }
})();
```

```html
<div class="selected">
  <select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="325">м3</option>
    <option value="500">шт</option>
  </select>
  <div class="short-price fx-1 nowrap value"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Чёт я не понимаю вопрос.. Eсли `e.value` вернёт значение, то какой-то переменной (допустим `price`) будет = `значение+'руб'`, а если значение пустое, то `price ===  1` , так?

Comment: сейчас скрипт возвращает просто цифры в value, как сделать, чтоб он просто вставлял 325 руб. например. Плюс как по умолчанию сделать чтоб был 1 option

Comment: Так.. Получается тут два вопроса.. 1. Чтобы `option` был "по-умолчанию", то изначально выставите ему атрибут `selected` в HTML. 2. Чтобы дописывалось `руб` к числу, то так где вставляете (`.innerText` или `.innerHTML`, или ещё как-то), добавьте `value+'руб'`, где `value` название вашей переменной с числом (`s.value`, если я правильно понимаю)

Comment: option selected не работает

Comment: Пока не выберешь option. цены нет.

Comment: При загрузке JS проверяйте им (JSом) выбранный `option[selected]`, и по нему выставляйте цену.

Comment: а как подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Можете взять код из функции и добавить его перед `e.addEventListener("change", n)`, только в переменной `var s = e.target` убрать `.target`

Comment: не получилось чтото

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Описание в коде, нужный фрагмент кода выделен комментариями.

```js
let rub = 'руб.'

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.selected'), function(e) {
    // Получаем значение по-умолчанию
    let select = e.querySelector('select'); // Берём в переменную select
    if(select && select.value != 0) { // Если он существует и его значение (по сути значение выбранного в нём option (именно value)) не равен 0 (это если у выбранного option value пустой или отсутствует)
      var v = select.parentNode.querySelector('.value'); // Тут так же как и в функции n(), берём .value который лежит выше
      v.style.display = 'inline-block'; // Ставим ему `inline-block`
      v.innerText = select.value+rub // и пишем значение select
    }
    // ------
    e.addEventListener("change", n)
  })

  function n(e) {
    var s = e.target;
    var v = s.parentNode.querySelector('.value');

    !+s.value && (v.style.display = 'none') || (v.style.display = 'inline-block', v.innerText = s.value+rub)
  }
```

```html
<div class="selected">
  <select>
    <option value="">Выберите..</option>
    <option value="325" selected>м3</option>
    <option value="500">шт</option>
  </select>
  <div class="short-price fx-1 nowrap value"></div>
</div>
```